# What is the use of tags in qlikview?

Tags: qlikview

What is the use of Tag fields use in QlikView
I found this syntax while Searching for it 
Syntax:
Tag fields fieldlist using mapname
Tag field fieldname with tagname

Answer (score 2):

For most cases you can tag fields as dimensions or measures. This will help the users/developers to understand the data model when they are building charts. For example: tagging field as dimension will highlight this field in the field list and put these fields at the top of the list

```
TAG FIELD Customer WITH $dimension;
TAG FIELDS Sales, NetSales WITH $measure;
TAG FIELDS CustomerNumber WITH MyTag;
```

For example executing the following script:

```
 TAG FIELD CustomerNumber, Name, Name2  WITH $dimension;
```

will produce the following result:

[image]

You can see how `CustomerNumber, Name and Name2` fields are highlighted and put on top of the field list

If you use using custom tags executing the following script:

```
TAG FIELDS CustomerNumber WITH MyTag;
```

Will tag the field with `MyTag` in the Table Viewer:

[image]

For more info please check 
https://community.qlik.com/docs/DOC-1332

Comment: is it possible to give a mapping command in a Tab statement? Like **Tab fields using [Mapping Load * inline [FieldName, Tag Col1,$dimension]];**